# How to place a table behind the status bar, Swift UIKit

Tags: swift, uikit, tableview, statusbar

Good afternoon! I set the table via storyboard. Changed the upper constrain to superview. I made my custom cell through xib. I want it to look like this:

[I want it to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiUFh.png)

[But now it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7bw3.png)

I've tried everything I can.

Answer (score 0):

**Give constraint left 8 right 8 and add shadow to your view.**

*Note - Your 1st image is in dark mode and the second image is in light mode.*